# Testing the onChange function with Jest in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd

How can I access the onChange function of the DatePicker (from Ant Design)? I tried to test the onChange Function, but can't access her? Is it possible to test the onChange function?

Deadline.js

```
export default function DeadlineView() {

  const [zieltermin, setZieltermin] = useState(false);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
  const [priority, setPrioioty] = useState("");
  const format = "HH:mm";

  const [deadline, setdeadline] = useRecoilState(deadline_state);

  let object = {
    start_date: startDate,
    target_date: null,
    reminder_time: null,
    priority: null,
  };

  

  return (
    <>
      {" "}
      <Space direction="vertical">
        <Space direction="horizontal">
          <Paragraph>Anfangsdatum wählen</Paragraph>
          <DatePicker
            data-testid="datePicker"
            onChange={(e) => {
              onChangeStartDate(e.$y, e.$M + 1, e.$d.getDate(), setStartDate);
            }}
          />
        </Space>

        <Space direction="horizontal">
          <Paragraph>Zieltermin</Paragraph>
          <Switch
            data-testid="switch-slider"
            onChange={() => onChangeZieltermin("", zieltermin, setZieltermin)}
          />
        </Space>

        <Space direction="horizontal">
          <Paragraph>Erinnerungszeit</Paragraph>
          <TimePicker defaultValue={moment("12:08", format)} format={format} />
        </Space>

        <Space direction="horizontal">
          <Paragraph>Priorität</Paragraph>
          <Select
            data-testid="prio"
            showSearch
            placeholder="Priority"
            optionFilterProp="children"
            onChange={() => onChangePriority(setPrioioty, "")}
            filterOption={(input, option) =>
              option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }
          >
            <Select.Option value="1">1</Select.Option>
            <Select.Option value="2">2</Select.Option>
            <Select.Option value="3">3</Select.Option>
          </Select>
        </Space>
      </Space>
    </>
  );
}
```

The onChangeStarteDate() function

```
export function onChangeStartDate(year, month, day, setStartDate) {
  console.log(year + "." + month + "." + day);
  setStartDate(year + "." + month + "." + day);
}
```

This is the Testing class, where I tried to render the whole component and then render a second time the specific component I want to test the onchange method. `expect(getDatePicker).toBeTruthy();` is true, but I'm not sure how to get access to the function and test it.

Deadline.spec.js

```
it("funct", async () => {
  // act(async () => {
  renderHook(() => useRecoilValue(deadline_state), {
    wrapper: RecoilRoot,
  });

  render(
    <AllProviders>
      <RecoilRoot>
        <DeadlineView />
      </RecoilRoot>
    </AllProviders>
  );
  const { getByTestId } = render(<DatePicker onChange={() => jest.fn()} />);
  const getDatePicker = getByTestId("datePicker");
  expect(getDatePicker).toBeTruthy();

  userEvent.change(getDatePicker, { target: { value: "2022-06-22" } });
  const text = await screen.findByText(/2022-06-22/i);
  expect(text).toBeInTheDocument;
  // });
});
```

Comment: What actually gets _rendered_ here? Does ant-design's `DatePicker` do anything with the `data-testid` prop? What do you mean _"get access to the function"_?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to trigger a date input in a Ant Design date picker. You should use keyboard input to modify the date picker value.

This is how I do it :

```
// you may need to adjust the selectors here

// clear the ant design input
userEvent.click(document.querySelector('.ant-picker-clear'));
// type a date, then enter to trigger the onChange event on date picker
userEvent.type(document.querySelector('.ant-picker input'), '2020-01-01{Enter}');
```

Then you could expect the callback to have been called, but in your case I'm not sure what to expect since `onChangeStartDate` is not defined in the code you provided.